# Div getting cut off using height:100% (includes a sticky footer)

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I know there's a lot of questions out there on this subject but none of the solutions work (checking for overflow:hidden;, setting min-height etc etc)

I'm working on this site - http://www.teamworksdesign.com/clients/ciw/our-work/advocacy/

At the moment everything within the site is getting cut off in IE9.

I've tried various fixes but none seem to affect this. It seems the body tag is the one that is doing the cutting as when you set an actual height in pixels, it fills that space.

Can anyone see what's going on?

---

Just to be clear, I have a sticky footer so that needs to be pushed to the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>  
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        height:auto!important;
        }  
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

All the modern browsers needed `height:100%;` but IE9 and below needed `height:auto!important`

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be the "height: 100%" CSS statement on line 31 in style.css that causes it.

Remove "height: 100%" on line 31 of style.css, and test if it affects anything else negatively, but from what I can see it works fine after that.

HTH.

Comment: If I take the height off the body tag then it doesn't push the footer to the bottom of the screen... although it does stop cutting things off.

Comment: The footer not being pushed to the bottom was not part of your original question. There are different ways to push footers to the bottom of the page, such as this (using Boostrap, but the concept remains the same): http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/